# adding .a file to codename one iOS project

Tags: codenameone

I want to add a .a file for codename one iOS project for device connection.
But I am getting the following build error whenever I send the iOS Debug build to the server.
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
  "_EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[RscMgr initWithProtocols:] in libRscMgrUniv.a(RscMgr.o)
  "_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[RscMgr initWithProtocols:] in libRscMgrUniv.a(RscMgr.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRscMgrUniv.a(RscMgr.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRscMgrUniv.a(RscMgr.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I am not able to link EAAccessory.framework to the iOS project in codename one. How can I link a framework to the iOS build?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Define the build argument:

```
ios.add_libs=EAAccessory.framework
```

If you need additional frameworks just separate them with ; in that argument.